# Is there any way to undo the effects of "git revert head"?

Tags: git, undo, revert

I've accidentally run the command against the wrong branch in my repository - is there a way to undo this change?

Comment: After reading the documentation for reset based on the advice below, git reset --hard head~1 solved it for me.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`git revert` just creates a new commit -- you can "remove" it with `git reset --hard HEAD^` (be more careful with it, though!)

Comment: Be careful with `git reset --hard HEAD^` as it will remove any uncommited changes.

Comment: If you do a `git stash` before `git reset --hard HEAD^` you can "save" your uncommited changes. After the `git reset --hard HEAD^` do a `git stash pop` to reload the uncommited changes into the current branch.

Answer (score 29):

The command `git revert` just creates a commit that undoes another.  You should be able to run `git revert HEAD` again and it'll undo your previous undo and add another commit for that.  Or you could do `git reset --hard HEAD~`.  But be careful with that last one as it erases data.

`HEAD~` means the commit before the current *HEAD*

Comment: No, it does not erase data. It just moves your branch pointer. The previous commit still exists, and you can see its ID by looking at `git reflog` (f.ex.). It will get garbage-collected in two months (default configuration), but you can turn off automatic garbage collection, and then *every single commit* you *ever* made will exist forever in that repository. They just aren't reachable via branches. But you can always find them using `git fsck`, and I’ve posted a recipe for browsing all commits that uses that.

Answer (score 4):

How about reverting the revert?

View git log and get the hash tag of the bad revert:

`git log -5`

Then do reverse the revert itself:

`git revert`

Comment: -1 this will create another commit, which is not really wanted here

Answer (score 0):

If you were prescient enough to have done this: `revert --no-commit master`, you can abort that with: `git revert --abort` per the `git status` advice:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
You are currently reverting commit dcc7c46.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git revert --continue")
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)
```