# GitHub Disaster: Undo A Revert?

Tags: github, undo, loss

I was using the visual editor for GitHub and was ready to commit changes to the master branch of my project.  However, when starting the visual editor, it would instantly popup with a message that there were conflicts.  It gave me the options to "continue or abort".  I kept trying to continue, but it wasn't working because a new window would pop up with so many conflicts that it stretched off the page.  So there may have been a button at the bottom of that window, but if so, it was impossible to access.  Anyway, I eventually gave up with "continue" and I hit abort...

Big mistake.  Git reverted all my work back to my last commit and "apparently" all the work I had done before the revert is gone.  Is there anyway to get it back?

To demonstrate this visually:

> commit1 -> commit2 -> commit3 -> (work in progress, not committed yet, )

tried to use the visual editor to commit, but wound up with this and lost my work:

> commit1 -> commit2 -> commit3

Edit: I "think" what happened is an accidental "rebase: updating head".  I need to undo that badly.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of this question (and if it is - good news for you!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662543/is-there-any-way-to-undo-the-effects-of-git-revert-head

Comment: Thanks, I had actually seen this thread, but I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for or not.  The data I lost has not been committed anywhere that I know of, and I'm not sure this loss was technically a revert, because it did NOT create a new commit :(

Comment: To provide more information, I think what accidentally happened is a "rebase: updating head".

Comment: what's a rebase updating head? I don't know github visual editor, but it looks like it was trying to pull from origin repo, and there were conflicts

Comment: I don't really know.  It just happens to be the most recent thing in my reflog.  The two most recent things are:
a44196f HEAD@{0}: rebase: updating HEAD
6725d6f HEAD@{1}: pull origin: Fast-forward

Comment: Update: GitHub tech support has no solutions for me at the moment but are still looking into it.