# What happens on several git reset --soft HEAD^^

Tags: git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to undo the effects of “git revert head”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662543/is-there-any-way-to-undo-the-effects-of-git-revert-head)

By mistake, I messed up with my GIT. Several times I executed git reset --soft HEAD^^ & then committed my changes. I never cared about what this command does !

Started like this; I created my local branch & then cherry pick the change. Later I followed 
git reset --soft HEAD^^ & then local commit every time.

I just realized that I did wrong !

Can anyone explain what this command does ? Any implication to my code ? 
Where exactly my HEAD should point to & how can I do that ?

Comment: @GrailsGuy: Nope, you linked to a post about `git revert`, not `git reset`.

Comment: Not a duplicate (`revert` != `reset`), but not a very good question either ("I did something particularly odd, now everything is fubar" -> probably not terribly useful to a general audience). That being said, the answer could be marked as duplicate (if that were possible), since it applies to many similar "odd" conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just see `git reflog` and find the original HEAD that you want to go to (referenced as `HEAD@{0}` etc.) and do `git reset --hard HEAD@{n}`

And try to run idempotent commands as much as possible. Avoid `HEAD~` etc and if you use, make sure you don't just randomly rerun them.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj. It worked. But under my working tree, there is one file which didn't reverted back ! Is there anyway I can grab the certain file for specific revision from remote repository ? Also if you can recommend GIT reading or video would be greatful. Thanks again.