# I reverted a merge in git, now how do I redo the merge?

Tags: git, version-control

I merged from a branch into master. Then I noticed that I solved the conflicts in a bad way, so I reverted the merge with the command:

```
git revert -m 1 *merge-hash*
```

my colleagues did a few commits after that. I tried to redo the merge, so that I could have a chance to resolve the conflicts in a different way. But, of course, it says that the branch is already merged in. How can redo the merge and resolve the conflicts in a good way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662543/is-there-any-way-to-undo-the-effects-of-git-revert-head

Comment: Do you have commits after the revert commit?

Comment: Yeah, ma there are a few

Answer (score 0):

use interactive rebase to get rid of the merge and the revert commits (simply omit them from the list)

This workflow is better suited to throwing away merges: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

Comment: That's of course a good workflow... but it doesn't solve my problem. Sorry, this is unrelated...

Comment: then do the interactive rebase. It's not part of the workflow.